# Latest entry in a group SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given the sample data below, I need a list of the ids whose latest entry is Rejected. Thus, I need to see id 2 because its latest is 6/4/2020 and that is Rejected. I do not want to see id 1 as its latest entry is Requested.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
    id int, 
    mydate datetime,
    status VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (1, '6/1/2020', 'Rejected')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (1, '6/2/2020', 'Requested')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (1, '6/3/2020', 'Rejected')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (1, '6/4/2020', 'Requested')

INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (2, '6/1/2020', 'Requested')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (2, '6/2/2020', 'Requested')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (2, '6/3/2020', 'Requested')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (2, '6/4/2020', 'Rejected')

SELECT * FROM #temp

SELECT id, MAX(mydate)
FROM #temp
WHERE status = 'Rejected'
GROUP BY id
```

This is my pathetic attempt so far

```
SELECT id, MAX(mydate)
FROM #temp
WHERE status = 'Rejected'
GROUP BY id
```

But this will only bring back the latest date in each group. I need a list where the latest entry was Rejected. I expect the answer to be embarrassingly simple but I'm having a heck of a time with this.

Thanks

Carl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this using `row_number()` function as shown below.

```
;WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT Id
        ,mydate
        ,STATUS
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY Id, status ORDER BY mydate desc
            ) row_num
    FROM #temp
    )
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE row_num = 1
    AND STATUS = 'Rejected'
```

Here is the live [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7b10f4156fcfebf5bca7d4e3c9ba64da) demo.

Answer (score 1):

One method uses aggregation and `having`:

```
select id
from #temp
group by id
having max(case when status = 'Rejected' then mydate end) = max(mydate);
```

This is almost a direct translation of your question:  the latest date for `'Rejected'` is the latest date for a given `id`.

More traditional methods use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from #temp t
where t.mydate = (select max(t2.mydate)
                  from #temp t2
                  where t2.id = t.id
                 ) and
      t.status = 'Rejected';
```

Or window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by mydate desc) as seqnum
      from #temp t
     ) t
where t.seqnum = 1 and t.status = 'Rejected';
```